# Ring of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that the ring of analytic function on a connected open set is a Bezout domain. Do we know what happens if we remove the hypothesis of connectedness? It is no longer a domain, but does the ring share the same nice properties like: every finitely generated ideal is principal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the ideal generated by some analytic function that is nonzero on $A$ and zero on $B$ and another analytic function that is nonzero on $B$ and zero on $A$, where $A$ and $B$ are distinct connected components of the open set on which they're defined?